# How to investigate SQL Server Timeout Error on ASP.net application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-timeout

We're facing a sever timeout error on NopCommerce - ASP.net MVC3 web application.

The error just resloves for sometime when we end the sql process. On ending it starts to work just fine for some time and then again it starts to occur.

This is happening since last few days only, before that it was working fine. Note that no major update has been made in its code.

We're clueless as what could be the problem and how to investigate and fix it? Is it a connection pool related issue or what?

Here is the stacktrace:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +296
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +415
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2657
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +88
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +114
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +505
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +1896
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +480
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +28
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +854
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +22
>      System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +269
>      System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter) +528

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dharmik Bhandari, There might be several issues. Try the following things

- Increase the pool size
- set CommandTimeOut = 0 (infinite)
- set ConnectionTimeOut = 0 (infinite)
- Release the connection resources as soon as the database functionality overs